# Split if else statements for code refactoring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, logic

Code : Which show only one error message on each time.

```
function isValidFields() {

        if (!$("#x").val()) {
            utilsService.setErrorClass('x');
            $scope.validationMessage.xErrorMessage = true;

        } else if (!$("#a").val()) {
            utilsService.setErrorClass('a');
            $scope.validationMessage.yErrorMessage = true;

        } else if (!$("#b").val()) {
            utilsService.setErrorClass('b');
            $scope.validationMessage.zgErrorMessage = true;

        } else if (!$("#c").val()) {
            utilsService.setErrorClass('c');
            $scope.validationMessage.cgErrorMessage = true;

        } else if (!$("#d").val()) {
            utilsService.setErrorClass('d');
            $scope.validationMessage.dgErrorMessage = true;


        } else if (!$("#e").val()) {
            utilsService.setErrorClass('e');
            $scope.validationMessage.egErrorMessage = true;


        } else if (!$("#f").val()) {
            utilsService.setErrorClass('f');
            $scope.validationMessage.fgErrorMessage = true;

        } else {
            $scope.validationMessage = {};
            return true;
        }
    }
```

What are best possible ways of making above code more readable and avoid many if else statement and avoid code duplications.

Comment: can i see the HTML and the what looks like angular controller?  all of this can be done in angular which would clean it up considerably (picking one tech)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with something like this..

```js
//mock scope
let $scope = {
  validationMessage: {
    xErrorMessage: null
  }
};

//mock utilServer
let utilsService = {
  setErrorClass: (id) => console.log(id)
}

function isValidFields() {
  let ids = ['x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

  // find the id of the first element with an empty value
  let first = ids.reduce((last, curr) => {
    return last || ((!$("#" + curr).val()) ? curr : null)
  }, null);

  // all elements had values
  if (!first) {
    $scope.validationMessage = {};
    return true;
  }

  utilsService.setErrorClass(first);
  $scope.validationMessage.xErrorMessage = true;
}
```

```css
input, button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="isValidFields()">try it</button>

<input typ="text" id="x">
<input typ="text" id="a">
<input typ="text" id="b">
<input typ="text" id="c">
<input typ="text" id="d">
<input typ="text" id="e">
<input typ="text" id="f">
```

*Note that this should be equivalent to the original code but it will be fragile based on the type of values `val()` returns.*

Comment: ,reduce method seems nt behaving curreclty, i need to check one field everytime i submit form with array order (as form field order). if one fails it should stop, it shloud nt show second error aswell.

Comment: reduce will only return 1 value, namely the first empty element's id.  I updated the code with mocks so you can step through and verify.

Comment: setErrorClass: (id) => console.log(id) can you tell me what design pattern it is?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the following way :

```
function isValidFields() {
 var fields = ['x','a','b','c','d','e','f'];
    $scope.validationMessage = {};
    for(var i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
        if(!$("#"+fields[i]).val()) {
            utilsService.setErrorClass(fields[i]);
            $scope.validationMessage[fields[i]+'ErrorMessage'] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```